# Highchart, updating spider web chart

Tags: highcharts

I'm using Highchart web chart. When I run it first time, it works well. Second time I run it by retrieving data from the backend using different parameters, but I get a strange error.

[image]

Any ideas? Looks like there's something wrong with destroying the element??

Comment: I would suggest trying to re-create on JSFiddle, it is possible that this is a highcharts bug

Comment: Please replicate your example as live demo, without it we have no chance to debug it.

Comment: people can't help you till they see your code. A jsFiddle or a code snippet is what will fetch you an answer